# Center text in html number input

Tags: css, html, input

I have a number input in html. I want to center the text (i.e. the input) that is inside. I of course did:

```
text-align: center;
```

which sort of works. The problem is though. The text is now centered when those arrows are shown. But when the arrows disappear, the text stays at the same position which now of course isn't the center anymore.

[image: Without arrows, the text does not appear centered.]

Comment: set arrows as backgrounds? maybe? - We need code (tryout codepen.io or jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can have the spinner buttons (arrows) always show:

```css
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Or you can have them always hidden:

```css
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

With either option, the contents will always be centred.

Comment: do we need moz or ms as well?

Comment: @emil Edge uses `-webkit` so there's no `-ms` equivalent. For moz you can try adjusting the [`-moz-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) property. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button

Answer (score 3):

I found that playing around with the width and padding-left properties worked in my situation because I required a fairly small box of width 45px.

So using

```
padding-left:10px;
width:45px;
text-align:center;
```

worked nicely.

https://jsfiddle.net/faanvme3/

Comment: Worked best for me without the `width` property

Answer (score 1):

Just this if you are using bootstrap:

Using css

```
input[type="number"] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Using bootstrap

```
<input type="number" class="text-center" min="1" max="99" name="quantity">
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved what you describe using position relative/absolute on the spinner.
The outcome is that the text of your input is centred while keeping the convenience of the spinner on top of it when necessary.

```
    input {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

In this example I assumed the spinner would be 1/8 of the size of the input, but that's up to you.